# Security Alert for links published by our App and on links pasted on Fan Page

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-apps

I am seeing security alert with the following message:

"The link you are trying to visit has been classified as potentially abusive by a Facebook partner. To learn more about staying safe on the Internet, visit Facebook's Security Page"

On siteadvisor, it says:

"We've tested millions of websites, but we haven't tested this one yet. Be the first one to submit feedback on it!"

I have a facebook app and I am unable to even go to the app via the Fan Page of my app. This is really annoying and I have no clue how to fix this. I have tried contacting Facebook as well but I am not sure if they will respond.

Comment: contact whoever runs whichever blacklist your site is on

Comment: Today apparently it got fixed on it own or may be as a result of me submitting the report to Facebook. The status on siteadvisor.com is still the same. This is quite weird. I hate magic!